# Conditional logic using for loops in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am starting to use PowerShell and am creating a conditional logic using the "For Loop". When I run the script, there is no result coming out. However, it will work if I replace those three functions by a single formula. 
Here is the script:

```
for ($OTK = 1; $OTK -le 10; $OTK++)
{
if ($OMAT = 6)
{
    if ($OMAF = 7)
    {
        function TK
        {
            param ([INT]$OTK)
            $OTK * 2
        }
        function MAT
        {
            param ([INT]$OMAT, $TK)
            $TK * $OMAT /5
        }
        function MAF
        {
            param ([INT]$OMAF,$MAT)
            $MAT * $OMAF /5
        }
    }
    Write-Output $MAF
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1, how to make this loop works?

2, how to call these functions independently from another source (ps1 or psm1)?

3, Is that possible to combine those two if statements? 
like`if ($OMAT = 6 -and $OMAF = 7)`.
I tried this format but it will not work.

Comment: `=` is assignment. Equality check is `-eq`. What results are you expect? You never assign something to `$MAF` in your code.

Comment: This loop is to calculate the value of MAF while `$OTK` keeps increasing. Those three functions can be replaced by `$MAF = ($OTK*2*$OMAT/5)*$OMAF/5`

Comment: Why do you use function then? What do you want to achieve, what can not be achieved by `$MAF = ($OTK*2*$OMAT/5)*$OMAF/5`?

Comment: I want to make some modules that contain some functions. The script can call different functions from modules. The function in the script can be replaced by another function without affecting other parts of the script. Like a modular program. That is why I do not want to use a single formula. I hope it explains what I am trying to do.

Comment: Each of the function in my script above will be put in the module later. This would be the second question I asked.

Comment: You can put whatever you want in your modules. Then conditionally call then function as you desire. I don't recommend conditionally _declaring_ functions which is what I see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "think" this is what you are after:

```
function TK
{
    param([int]$OTK)
    $OTK * 2
}

function MAT
{
    param([int]$OMAT, $TK)
    $TK * $OMAT / 5
}

function MAF
{
    param([int]$OMAF,$MAT)
    $MAT * $OMAF / 5
}

$OMAT = 6
$OMAF = 7

for ($OTK = 1; $OTK -le 10; $OTK++)
{
    if ($OMAT -eq 6 -and $OMAF -eq 7)
    {
        MAF $OMAF (MAT $OMAT (TK $OTK))
        # (TK $OTK) is the output of TK that is fed into
        # MAT which takes $OMAT and the output of TK, that is fed into
        # MAF which takes $OMAF and the output of MAT
    }
}
```

In your original script, you define functions but never call them.  As it pointed out in the comments you were using `=` for comparisons as well as assignment.  In PowerShell, the equality comparison opertors are `-eq`, `-ieq` and `-ceq`.